# Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path changes the path during normal debug and a test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp

I am creating a UWP app and have created a file using Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path for the path. When in debug mode, it has one location for the path, then when running a unit test, it has a different location for the path and therefore will not find the file since it is a different location. Has anybody encountered this before? I've been searching and haven't seen anything on why it does this between debugging and debugging a unit test.

Comment: What are the two respective paths? Can you print them to Debug output or to a log file somewhere?

Comment: You are trying to use system path or relative to LocalFolder?

Comment: The normal debug path gives me this: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Packages\ecb2e31f-f0a6-4cc5-8aa9-8cd1b887d5ed_2xgss9s9ewh1t\LocalState The test gives me: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Packages\c110be4d-26ac-4a4e-9c34-952c8f5ebd9d_2xgss9s9ewh1t\LocalState

Comment: Why does your unit test need a file from app's `LocalFolder`? Unit tests should initialize all the required data themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The each project has different `Package family name`. And the `LocalFolder.Path` is base on the `Package family name` in debug. Your debug project `Package name` is `ecb2e31f-f0a6-4cc5-8aa9-8cd1b887d5ed` and the `PublisherId` is `2xgss9‌​s9ewh1t`. So the `Package family name` is `ecb2e31f-f0a6-4cc5-8aa9-8cd1b887d5ed_2xgss9‌​s9ewh1t`. The `unit test` is another project, so it has a different `Package family name`. For more info, see [Package family name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.familyname.aspx).

The folder is created by first debug. You can change `Package name` in `Package.appxmanifest`. The `LocalFolder.Path` will change when you debug it again. And the folder will change to the new `Package family name`.

The unit test Project can not create the folder when you debug it. But it can get the `LocalFolder.Path` that is a non-existent URI.